# left join Query with same column show duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables named

> tbl_1st
>   tbl_2nd
>   tbl_3rd

every time record enter in first table with column name tt as primary key. Which is used by other two table as foreign key, (but other two table has tt2 contain primary key)

data on these three tables are :

**First Table**

[image]

**Second Table**

[image]

**Third Table**

[image]

when I run this Query

```
select * from tbl_1st
left join tbl_2nd on tbl_1st.tt = tbl_2nd.Tt
left join tbl_3rd on tbl_1st.TT = tbl_3rd.tt
where tbl_1st.tt = 100000000000000001
```

it shows duplicate record in it, what I want is, if on particular tt 2nd and 3rd table match tt2 it merge this in one row, and remaining show null or other.

suppose in this case i has to shown only 2 reocrds, but if I change where condition as

> where tbl_1st.tt = 100000000000000002

it shows only 3 record, how can it happens? any Idea

**EDIT**

**DataTypes**
tt is numeric(20,0)
tt2 is numeric(22,0)
DateTime is datetime
status is bit

**Output:**
[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image]

**Case 2 Output :**
[image]

**But expected 3 rows in this case.**

Comment: What is the type of `tt`?  For something that long, you should probably store it as a string.

Comment: Edit my question, please review @GordonLinoff

Comment: It's how the joins work. Could you provide the expected result of your query?

Comment: @dean i have added output .. kindly review

Comment: how do you choose last TT2 and status?

Comment: @anaspa i want, this output. i want to merge this as rows

Comment: Does tbl_2nd.TT2 relate to tbl_3rd.TT2?  If so you need to incorporate this into the join between the two

Comment: have you tried where t1.tt = 100000000000000001 and t2.tt2 <> t3.tt2

Comment: @SteveFord this also not working

Comment: @RichardBoyce 
tbl2nd and tbl_3rd relate sometime, but not every time

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be joining between `tbl_2nd` and `tbl_3rd` like this:

```
select * from tbl_1st
left join tbl_2nd on tbl_1st.tt = tbl_2nd.Tt
left join tbl_3rd on tbl_2nd.TT2 = tbl_3rd.tt2 -- <-- Notice the change in alias
where tbl_1st.tt = 100000000000000001
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't work on case 2, i mean when I run
where tbl_1st.tt = 100000000000000002

Comment: Are you able to show what the desired result is in case 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from tbl_1st
left join tbl_2nd on tbl_1st.tt = tbl_2nd.Tt
left join tbl_3rd on tbl_1st.tt = tbl_3rd.tt AND tbl_2nd.Tt = tbl_3rd.tt 
where tbl_1st.tt = 100000000000000001
```